# Fetch suggestions dynamically from an api for input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to fetch the suggestion for input field in my react component.  I trigger onChange event on this input field which then makes an api call and fetched the relevant content.

This is how I am doing it

```
<span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Add tag" list="languages" id='tags-input-field'
           className={`addtag-input ${this.state.showAddTagInputArray.findIndex(x => x === item.id) !== -1 ? "" : "hidden"}`}
           onChange={this.searchTags.bind(this)}
           />
    <datalist id='languages'>
        {this.state.existingTags && this.state.existingTags.map((item,i)=>{
            return <option value= {item.name} />
        })}
    </datalist>
</span>
```

And this is "searchTags" function

```
searchTags(){

            let req = fetch(url + document.getElementById("tags-input-field").value,
                {
                    method: "GET",
                    headers: {
                        "Authorization": "Token " + this.props.token_reducer.token,
                        "content-type": "application/json"
                    }
                })
        req.then(response => response.json()
        ).then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            this.setState({existingTags:response})
        })
    }
```

**Problem**: Problem with this approach is, searchTags() gets fired for each letter I press. Suppose I type 10 letters very fast then 10 requests starts and this is hanging my system. How should I approach this problem?

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve: you could add a button which will fire the API call, or listen to "enter press" or "blur" event, or fire the call when the minimum length of inserted text is 3 chars for instance...

Answer (score 1):

You can delay the ajax request using something like `setTimeout(fetch, n)`, and clear the timeout on each key press.  This causes it to only search after they have stopped typing for at least `n` milliseconds.

```
this.state = {
    searchTimeout: false
}

searchTags(){
    clearTimeout(this.state.searchTimeout);
    let searchTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        let req = fetch(url + document.getElementById("tags-input-field").value,
                {
                    method: "GET",
                    headers: {
                        "Authorization": "Token " + this.props.token_reducer.token,
                        "content-type": "application/json"
                    }
                })
        req.then(response => response.json()
        ).then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            this.setState({existingTags:response})
        })
    }.bind(this), 500);
    this.setState({searchTimeout});
}
```

Comment: Still this hangs. When I do backspace it hangs. I tried increasing that time from 500 to 2000 but that also doesn't make it smooth

Comment: is it because the list is too long?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common problem with search inputs. The simplest solution that covers the common use cases is to debounce the call.

```
constructor () {
 this.searchTags.bind(this);
 this.debouncedSearch = this.debounce(this.searchTags, 300);
}
debounce = (func, wait = 100) => {
  let timeout;
  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      func.apply(this, args);
    }, wait);
  };
};

// in render
onChange={this.debouncedSearch}
```

Lodash also has a great off-the-shelf [debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#debounce).

You also need to [add a key](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) to each list item since you are rendering a list. [Don't use index as your key](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318), choose a unique identifier.

```
<datalist id='languages'>
  {this.state.existingTags && this.state.existingTags.map((item,i)=>{
    return <option key={item.id} value= {item.name} />
  })}
</datalist>
```

Comment: backspacing hangs the system all over using this also.

Comment: Is it because the list is too long?

Comment: Added a suggestion to add a key to your list item, how long is your list?